# How do i install Sqlite 3 and Sequelize on a project manually?

Tags: sqlite

I've been trying to use these programs but it won't install. I get this message when trying to install sqlite 3. And when i do "node ." it just tells me to install it manually and i looked up a tutorial but it wasn't JUST for discord.

```
    C:\Users\roser\OneDrive\Desktop\ROSYBREE>npm install sqlite3
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> sqlite3@5.0.1 install C:\Users\roser\OneDrive\Desktop\ROSYBREE\node_modules\sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.1 and node@14.15.3 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  nothing.c
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  nothing.vcxproj -> C:\Users\roser\OneDrive\Desktop\ROSYBREE\node_modules\sqlite3\build\Release\\nothing.lib
  unpack_sqlite_dep
  The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209
,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\Users\roser\OneDrive\Desktop\ROSYBREE\node_modules\sqlite3\build\
deps\action_before_build.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\roser\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\ROSYBREE\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\napi-v6-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\roser\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\ROSYBREE\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\napi-v6-win32-x64" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=6" "--node_napi_label=napi-v6"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\roser\OneDrive\Desktop\ROSYBREE\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\roser\OneDrive\Desktop\ROSYBREE\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\roser\OneDrive\Desktop\ROSYBREE\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\roser\OneDrive\Desktop\ROSYBREE\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\roser\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\ROSYBREE\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\roser\OneDrive\Desktop\ROSYBREE\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\roser\OneDrive\Desktop\ROSYBREE\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\roser\OneDrive\Desktop\ROSYBREE\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
npm WARN ROSYBREE@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN ROSYBREE@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@5.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@5.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\roser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-10T19_45_31_708Z-debug.log
```